# npm not installing node_modules

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I try to install angular via npm but it's not creating any node_modules directory. How come?
See the screenshot below:

```
 MacBook-Pro-di-Sandro:~ sandropalmieri$ cd Documents/mycode/
 MacBook-Pro-di-Sandro:mycode sandropalmieri$ cd angular1
 MacBook-Pro-di-Sandro:angular1 sandropalmieri$ mkdir testApp2
 MacBook-Pro-di-Sandro:angular1 sandropalmieri$ cd testApp2
 MacBook-Pro-di-Sandro:testApp2 sandropalmieri$ npm install angular@1.4.7
 angular@1.4.7 ../../../../node_modules/angular
 MacBook-Pro-di-Sandro:testApp2 sandropalmieri$ ls
 MacBook-Pro-di-Sandro:testApp2 sandropalmieri$ ls
 MacBook-Pro-di-Sandro:testApp2 sandropalmieri$
```

As you can see the folder is empty. 
I am currently using Node v. 4.1.2 and npm 2.14.4
Any idea of what's going on?
Thanks a lot
Sandro

Comment: Do you have a package.json in your projet ? 
npm is looking for the first package.json he can found, and it seems to e you home directory

Comment: No I don't. I thought npm would create the package.json by itself. Should I create the package.json first?

Comment: Yes. To create `package.json` you should write `npm init -yes`

Comment: But it seems you are creating web client application, so maybe you should use `bower` instead?

Comment: If you want to start a new project try yeoman it will help you with some project generator

Comment: thanks. Now I was able to generate the node_modules and the package.json. Anyway when I try to call in a js file using the 'require' function the console log says that require is not defined. I am trying using browserify but still getting the same message 'require is not defined'. I need to understand better the tooling system.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  MacBook-Pro-di-Sandro:testApp2 sandropalmieri$ npm install angular@1.4.7
>  angular@1.4.7 ../../../../node_modules/angular
> ```

There is a parent directory with package.json, where angular is being installed.

```
ls ../../../../node_modules
```

And you will see node_modules containing angular.

Depending on where you want it to be installed, you can run `npm init .` to create a package.json and then `npm install angular` to install it locally in that directory.